# says Can not Play Audio Because Audio Is Disabled When it's not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I got this error saying:

```
Can not play a disabled audio source
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Even though I've checked and all my audio sources are enabled.

Here's a picture of the AudioSource to prove it's not Disabled
[image]

Comment: that's strange, insert `Debug.Break ();` just before you play your audio to be absolutely sure. it will pause your game in editor.

Comment: You have tagged the question "compiler-errors". Which compiler are you using? Please post the actual compiler errors and the pertinent source code. Please also tag the question with the programming language name.

Comment: This error could be caused by a mistake in your code, and not just by the AudioSource's state; as an example, you could have disabled an object having the audio component "End Fight", and then trying to access it later. You should post your code in order to receive further help!

Comment: @NikaKasradze **Type That Were?**

Comment: @SpikyCat sorry I thought you where playing it from the code. Well, I don't know, is the GameObject enabled? and all of the parent GameObjects too.

Comment: alright guys, this was  a humor error just a problem with a  script I had that stopped the music when I used the pause menu and that was the problem